# Problems with CSS clip-path in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, path, clip, clip-path

The following Website project using the CSS clip-path property works fine in Safari but breaks in Google Chrome (it also works fine in Google Chrome until a few weeks). Is this a bug in Google Chrome regarding CSS clip-path?

https://css-clip-text.webflow.io

Here is the CSS code I've used:

```
<style>
.text-holder {
clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
}
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   /* IE10+ */
.text-holder {clip: rect(0,auto,auto,0);}
.text {display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 50vh;} 
}
@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
   /* Edge 12+ */ 
.text-holder {clip: rect(0,auto,auto,0);}
.text {display: block; width: 100%;  text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 50vh;} 
}
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    /* Edge 16+ */ 
.text-holder {clip: rect(0,auto,auto,0);}
.text {display: block; width: 100%;  text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 50vh;} 
}
</style>
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Chrome and "clip-path". For me it helped to set the  CSS property `transform: translateZ(0);` to all elements inside the element with the "clip-path" property.

Comment: this works! thank you very much for this solution!

Comment: and I had to put width 100% on the container (figure) with the clip-path applied. thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's Stardate 100591.97 and thanks to the chrome browser I had to give up trying to use clip-path: inset(); and use clip-path: polygon(); instead.

```
.text-holder {
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
```

}

[image]

https://www.stoacademy.com/tools/stardate.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work in Chrome if you apply a z-index to each `.h1 .text`.  See screen shot below.

[image: Screen shot from Chrome]

Comment: thank you, but I tried it out and this solution doesn't work.

Comment: the problem only appears in Google Chrome Browser. In Safari and Edge the clipping works correct.

Comment: Hmm. That sceenshot is from Chrome...but on a mac....maybe it's Chrome on a PC?